# Access query to group by and count vlues, including nulls

Tags: ms-access

I have an access table TABLE1 with one column called DATA. Values are like this:

```
Row DATA
1   a
2   a
3   b
4   c
5   
6   
7   c
```

I run

```sql
select DATA, count(*) from TABLE1 
group by DATA
```

I am expecting a result of

```
DATA COUNT
a    2
b    1
c    2
Null 2
```

I got it that access says it ignores NULLS in COUNT.  If I can't use that, what can I use to get the result I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The original query:

```
select DATA, count(*) from TABLE1 
group by DATA
```

should work on Null values without problem, only the null values displayed as empty field.

If you really want to display `Null` for null values, just modify the query as following:

```
select nz(DATA,"Null") AS ... , count(*) AS ... from TABLE1 
group by DATA
```

Answer (score 0):

This SQL will resolve your Null problem:

`SELECT DATA, Count(Nz([DATA])) AS DataCount FROM Table1 GROUP BY DATA;`

Be aware that if you have blanks in your Data then they will be counted in the Null group.